# Как в Golang вывести каждый второй символ в строке

Tags: строки, golang

Как я могу вывести каждый второй символ в строке? Пример:

```
Hello, my name is Jack!
```

Должно быть что-то такого (может быть ошибка): `el,maeiak`

Comment: Как обычно: пройти циклом по буквам и напечатать каждый второй символ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стало интересно итерируема ли строка в Go и я написал следующий код:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    src := "Hello, my name is Jack!"
    for i, ch := range src {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%c", ch)
        }
    }
}
```

У меня получился следующий вывод:

```
Hlo ynm sJc!
```

Comment: Выводится, начиная с первого символа (индекс 0). Чтобы выводить со второго, надо проверять на i%2==1.

Comment: Спасибо, то что мне нужно! :)

Comment: @Эникейщик и Вам спасибо за эту поправку:)